# Using resources defined in another assembly in a Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

The resources file containing the language specific strings for my application are defined in a DLL that is common to the front-end and back-end of my application.  The front-end is a WPF application, but there's a small WinForms app that is displayed when the program is running and the user starts an upgrade to a later version.  I need to modify this WinForms application so it uses the resource strings in the common resource DLL.

I have added a reference to the resource DLL to the WinForm application.  I have also set the `Localizable` property of the form to true.

There are a couple of labels on this form and a button, all of which I need to display strings that are read from the common resource file.  How do I specify to each of the controls that it should get the text from the common resource DLL?

Comment: That's not possible, you'll have to write that code yourself.

Comment: I figured that.  In fact, the point of my question was exactly how do I do that?  Sorry I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but this is how I addressed the issue.

I added code to set the `Text` property of each control in the `MainForm.cs` file, in the constructor method, after the call to `InitializeComponent()`, like this:

```
public MainForm() {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Text = Car.UpdateDialog_Title;
    lblLine1.Text = Car.UpdateDialog_lblLine1;
    lblLine2.Text = Car.UpdateDialog_lblLine2;
    butOk.Text = Car.Common_OK;
}
```

This works.  I also set the `Localizable` property for the form back to `false`, since the program doesn't have its own localization resources.